# How to use JSON and ajax without getting errors

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to get some JSON from an external PHP file using AJAX and put it in an option list.

I have XAMPP and got Apache and Mysql running, and I've got everything working for 1 JSON object, but when I add the second one it gives me an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0.
Sorry if I'm bad at explaining I'm new.

Here is my php:

```
  <?php

    //connection to mysql(my connection code goes here)

    //feeders
$feeders = [];

$sql = "SELECT Name FROM feeder";
$result = $conn->query($feeder_sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $feeders[] = $row["Name"];
   };
};
$feeder_list = array("feeders" => $feeders);
echo json_encode($feeder_list);

//recorders
$recorders = [];

$sql = "SELECT Name FROM recorders";
$result = $conn->query($recorder_sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $recorders[] = $row["Name"];
   };
};
$recorder_list = array("recorders" => $recorders);
echo json_encode($recorder_list);

?>
```

And here is my Jquery:

```
$(function() {
var feeders;
var recorders;

$.get('home.php', function(data){
feeders = JSON.parse(data).feeders;
for (var i = 0; i < feeders.length; i++) {
$("#feeders").append("<option value =" + feeders[i] + ">" + feeders[i] + "</option>");
}
recorders = JSON.parse(data).recorders;
for (var i = 0; i < recorders.length; i++) {
$("#recorders").append("<option value =" + recorders[i] + ">" + recorders[i] + "</option>");
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **echo** multiple times in server side which is combined response for **jQuery** part. Combine your both query results in one array and encode and echo once in the end. Adjust your **jQuery** part accordingly.

```
$output = [];

//feeders
$feeders = [];

$sql = "SELECT Name FROM feeder";
$result = $conn->query($feeder_sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $feeders[] = $row["Name"];
   };
};
$output['feeders'] = $feeders;

//recorders
$recorders = [];

$sql = "SELECT Name FROM recorders";
$result = $conn->query($recorder_sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $recorders[] = $row["Name"];
   };
};
$output['recorders'] = $recorders;

// final output
echo json_encode($output);
```